# Is the Safari Web Browser an Open Source Project?

Tags: safari, open-source

I'm interested in doing some development against the Safari browser but I'm not sure if it's an open source project or not? I know webkit is open source but that doesn't mean the browser is.

I've emailed apple but they haven't been very responsive so I'm wondering if anyone on stackoverflow has any idea?

Comment: Please don't make another web browser!  We have enough already!

Comment: If someone can come up with a good 3D web browser that may be useful, so we can flip pages around on a cube. :)  Unless people are experimenting we won't make any major changes in browsers.

Comment: @Soviut: I'm definitely not interested in making another web browser, I just wanted to play around with how safari works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Safari is closed source. Only the Webkit portion is open source.

Comment: Of course, WebKit is nearly all of the code.  The Safari app is a pretty thin layer over the framework.

Comment: how is Safari closed source, given the GPL license of Webkit?

Comment: @optikradio Safari merely incorporates the library Webkit, it does not extend/alter it. Webkit is simply an HTML renderer. All other aspects of a browser (back/forward navigation, javascript implementation, history, etc...) are separate.

Comment: @optikradio WebKit is licensed under the "Lesser GPL" which allows use in proprietary programs, where the regular GPL does not. The regular GPL does NOT allow incorporation even if you do not extend alter. Under regular GPL your ENTIRE application MUST be released as source code. Lesser GPL does not have this restriction. This is why safari is able to use webkit. See http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/why-not-lgpl.html and http://www.webkit.org/coding/lgpl-license.html

Comment: I've find that Epiphany (gnome web) reproduces most of the issues seen in Safari as a web developer.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at Konqueror, as it is the basis for Safari, and what you want to add may be added there, and if it gets into the trunk it may find it's way into Safari.

http://www.konqueror.org/features/browser.php

Answer (score 2):

[Chromium](http://code.google.com/chromium/) is also based on WebKit, the rendering engine behind Safari. If you want to look at a fully functional browser based on WebKit, Chromium is probably your best bet.

Comment: Chromium is open, not Chrome. The link does go to Chromium, though.